# Can not open this .tif image file

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have an image file (Baltic Sea Pressure Index Image) with ".tif" extension and it also has ".ovr" and ".tfw" files with the same name in the same directory (I'm not sure what they are for, my research lead to ambiguous information). 
All I'm doing is running the code below:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('BSPI.tif')
im.show()
```

And it throws this error:

```
ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

I've also tried:

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread("BSPI.tif")
cv.imshow("test",img)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

now I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in 
cv::imshow, file D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-
3.3.0\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 333
```

I've also tried using gdal:

```
from osgeo import gdal

img = gdal.Open("BSPI.tif")
img = np.array(img.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
print(img)
```

I got this output:

```
[[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
...
[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]]
```

I got the same "nan" array with the following code using rasterio:

```
import rasterio as rio

img = rio.open("BSPI.tif")
print(img.read())
```

Is there any different way to read or process a .tif image? Or could something be wrong with the image? I can view the image by double clicking just fine. It's a black and white image of the Baltic Sea, as expected.

**Edit:** It turns out Gdal and rasterio are able to open the file. It's just that the image has "nan" vaues where (assumably) the black pixels are for some reason. But I am still not sure of the validity of this tif file. I couldn't find a way to share files through stakcoverflow but if you can understand what's wrong, you can access the files [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lydhr59dyfx64tpPhJZ5IH7dbXcyksrs). Thank you in advance. I really need to fix this.

Comment: its most likely that the name or path to the image is wrong

Comment: What program is it that can display the image when you double-click? Does that program still display it correctly if you move the 2 accompanying files somewhere else temporarily? Try running `tiffdump BSPI.tif`

Comment: The path and the name are true. The program is windows' photo viever. And yes, it does still display it correctly even if there is only the ".tif" file. Where do I run `tiffdump`? In cmd?

Comment: Yes, `tiffdump` comes with `libtiff` and you run it at command prompt. Alternatively, you can run ImageMagick to check what the file contains with `magick identify -verbose BSPI.tif` (omit the word `magick` if v6 or earlier)

Comment: If you care to make the file available, I'll take a look at it for you.

Comment: I have had a look at the file you shared, and can't do much with it. It appears to be tiled into 128x128 tiles and to be a single channel of 32-bit floating point samples. Sorry :-(